# What's the fastest a medieval projectile could go, if it was powered by human muscles?

Tags: weapons, hard-science, medieval, engineering

How fast could a human-powered medieval projectile go?

Rules:

- The weapon must be made of materials available in medieval times: wood, steel, catgut, bone, rope, etc. No modern composites or plastics.
- Engineering must be done to tolerances achievable in medieval times.
- Human muscle power must be the power source. No explosives, no fires, no battery piles.
- Electricity-powered weapons like railguns or coilguns are not allowed. Magnets are not allowed.
- It is allowed to store the human muscle power as elastic potential energy (e.g. a bow), kinetic energy (e.g. a flywheel), gravitational potential energy (e.g. a trebuchet), compressed air, or thermal storage. Other energy storage methods are not allowed.
- If necessary, it is allowed to have many humans working together to power the weapon.
- The design of weapon does not need to have been known to medieval engineers, as long as it uses medieval materials in conformance with these rules.
- Speed of projectile is measured at time of release.

So, what are the upper limits for projectile speed? Can we get to 800 m/s, like a sniper bullet?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138132/discussion-on-question-by-causative-whats-the-fastest-a-medieval-projectile-cou).

Answer (score 4):

Empirical evidence: the whip.

The crack of the whip happens when the whip tip reaches the speed of sound in air (about 330-340 m/s depending on air temperature). Massaging [the equations](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Eura-reports/031/Taft.Jefferson/Report.pdf) seems to indicate that up to three times that is possible without needing special materials (crude springs have been available for a long time).

This means that a projectile speed of 1000 m/s is **possible** (or should I say, *not impossible*).

On the other hand, actually *achieving* this speed requires either luck, or *knowledge* or *research* - the means to investigate whether the speed is going up or down with different setups, and even the awareness that a higher speed is *possible* at all.

None of these things, except luck, were available in the Middle Ages.

The speed of such a projectile, detaching from the whip exactly at the time of the crack, would also probably rapidly fall off due to aerodynamic considerations (adding fins to it seems excessive. Again, it is *not impossible*).

Also, nothing has been said about *aiming* the projectile.